# Applescript need to trim printline

Tags: applescript

I have script line 
`set usedSpace to (do shell script "df -hl | grep 'disk1' | awk print $5}'") as integer`
it gives me number with % but i want only the number without %

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a text value to a number in AppleScript if there are non-numeral characters in the string.  You first must remove the unwanted characters, then convert:

```
set usedSpace to (do shell script "df -hl  | grep 'disk1' | awk '{ print $5}'")

set numberOnly to characters 1 thru -2 of usedSpace as text as number
```